# Admob 6.8.0: manually remove, hide or disable banners

Tags: ios, xcode, admob

There are tons of similar questions here, but none of the solutions are working on the latest AdMob SDK. At least I couldn't make it work.

Loading:

```
- (void)AdMob_Banner_On
 {
    bannerView_.adUnitID = kAdMobID;
    bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
    [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
    (...)
}
```

They are running perfectly, and now removing... all solutions I found are quite simple, but they don't work:

```
 - (void)AdMob_Banner_Off {

     NSLog(@"Admob: Turning Off");

     bannerView_.hidden = YES;
     [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];
     [bannerView_ setDelegate:nil];
     bannerView_ = nil;
 }
```

Some times I **need** all screen available, I can't show ads all the time. Any ideas?

Comment: What doesn't work? Where is your code that is calling these two methods?

Comment: The second one doesn't work, that is the question. How to remove it, make it stop, hide, etc. The first one is called on viewDidLoad, banners show up perfectly. The second one gets called by an IBAction, when it show something on the app that requires full screen, and that doesn't work.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and confirm that your second method is getting called? GADBannerView is a subclass of UIView so it should respond appropriately. I've been able to remove the banner successfully in the sample project provided by Google.

Comment: I figure it out! Thanks to you I downloaded the sample code from Google again to investigate and I found the solution. The problem was that the lines in the loading code were on the wrong order, and for some reason that was making the bannerView unable to be removed from the Superview!

Comment: Great! If you've solved the problem please post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem, here is how I fix it.

The problem was that I was that the lines on the "AdMob_Banner_On" method were inverted.

Although the banner was showing up perfectly, it made the bannerView_ unable to respond to any other command, so even if the AdMob_Banner_Off was called, nothing was happening.

Now the code that works. The first thing you should do it to set the position of the banner, and then calling it. That was my problem. This code should work fine:

Turning on:

```
 - (void)AdMob_Banner_On {

     NSLog(@"Admob: Turning On");

     // Making it on the bottom:

     CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,self.view.frame.size.height - CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height);
          bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait origin:origin];

     bannerView_.adUnitID = kAdMobID;
     bannerView_.rootViewController = self;
     bannerView_.delegate = self;
     [self.view addSubview:bannerView_];
     [bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

 }


 - (void)AdMob_Banner_Off: {

     NSLog(@"Admob: Turning Off");

     [bannerView_ removeFromSuperview];

 }
```

With this code you can turn on and off the banner as you want. This is useful to apps that can't show the banner all the time.

Answer (score 0):

initAd must be in `viewDidLoad`
I solved by it.