# Is there any delegate methods to hide google Ads without add button to hide Ad Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, google-ads-api

I am working on Bottom Banner Ad in table view.It's working fine but client wants to delete the ad when they don't need.So How can I do this???can you give me a suggesstion or code  when i try to delete tha ad it's not deleted see my code and image below:

```
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    self.bannerview = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
    self.bannerview.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-4719922286387557/3468269154665";
    self.bannerview.rootViewController = self;
    [self.navigationController.toolbar addSubview:self.bannerview];
    [self.bannerview loadRequest:request];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will help you, check it once ....
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23450656/7369234

Comment: Is there any delegate methods to hide google Ads without add button to hide Ad?Actually, it's very easy to add button and hide the banner view...But in my app, i customize show many things.Once if I add button it will collapse entire layout.